# Compiling C/GTK within Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gcc, gtk

I'm fiddling around with the C/C++ version of Eclipse to build a simple GTK app. However, I can't seem to be able to compile a GTK sample from within Eclipse. I can compile a simple Hello World style test app, so I know the tool chain itself is working. However, the moment I start adding GTK into the mix the compiler comes up with errors. The funny thing is that I can compile the examples outside the Eclipse environment just fine. E.g., I'm using the examples on [this](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk-tutorial/stable/c39.html#SEC-HELLOWORLD) page and following the instructions given there let me build a working binary.

I think the first problem is that the main GTK include file is referenced differently when I try to compile within Eclipse. The non-Eclipse version I can compile with (as in the example):

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
```

However, within Eclipse this doesn't work. I need to change it to:

```
#include <gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h>
```

The include file can then be found but the compilation process then starts to throw errors about the GtkWidget type. E.g.:

```
#include <gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    GtkWidget *window;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_widget_show  (window);

    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

Results in these errors:

```
make all 
Building file: ../src/main.c
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/main.d" -MT"src/main.d" -o"src/main.o" "../src/main.c"
../src/main.c: In function ‘main’:
../src/main.c:7: error: ‘GtkWidget’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../src/main.c:7: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
../src/main.c:7: error: for each function it appears in.)
../src/main.c:7: error: ‘window’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../src/main.c:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gtk_init’
../src/main.c:11: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gtk_window_new’
../src/main.c:11: error: ‘GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../src/main.c:12: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gtk_widget_show’
../src/main.c:14: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gtk_main’
make: *** [src/main.o] Error 1
```

Not sure how to go about this. Any assistance would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right click the Eclipse project and select properties. From the Configuration drop down, select `[ All configurations ]`. Then on the Tool Settings tab select `GCC C Compiler` (default) and add the following to the end `Command line pattern` (Expert settings) box:

```
`pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`
```

Do the same thing for the `GCC C Linker` option.

If you don't want to start your include paths with gtk-2.0 than also add the include directory (/usr/include/gtk-2.0) like aardvark suggested.

Comment: i cannot find configuration drop down.can you please help me?

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using and what type of project did you create? The original question is from '09, so things might have changed or moved around a bit in the Eclipse UI.

Comment: For 2019, the place you need to add the option is : In the project window select Project > Properties > Choose C/C++ Build > Settings > Under 'Tool Settings' choose your compiler GCC C++ or GCC C compiler ,on the right side you can find "Expert settings: Command line pattern:" , add the line `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0` towards the end.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the gtk directory to the build path:

Go into project Properties -> C/C++ build -> Settings -> Tool settings -> Directories and add it under Include paths.

Comment: Thanks. That took care of Eclipse not recocnizing the gtk/gtk.h but when I compile now I get so many errors. The last two are kinda weird: ../src/main.c:16: error: old-style parameter declarations in prototyped function definition
../src/main.c:16: error: expected ‘{’ at end of input

Answer (score 1):

A long waited relief considering the pkg-config support for Eclipse CDT is coming soon.

The support is under development and will be integrated to CDT around August or so.

The most important feature is that an easy to use user interface allows to select the required packages.

Project website:
http://code.google.com/p/pkg-config-support-for-eclipse-cdt/

Update:
Feel free to test the beta version:
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pkg-config-support-eclipse-cdt 
Feedback is appreciated!

Comment: it seems to be broken - only the libs are added but not the paths (in Eclipse Oxygen)