# How do I tell cmake to use Command line pattern?

Tags: cmake

Quoted from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315091/compiling-c-gtk-within-eclipse/1315207#1315207):

```
`pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`
```

Suppose `FindGTK2()` is not working,but `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0` is OK,how do I include requires lib/header files?

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

- Modify [FindGTK2.cmake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#module:FindGTK2) to look in the correct locations
- Add the GTK prefix to [CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#variable:CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH)
- Use the [FindPkgConfig](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#module:FindPkgConfig) module to perform the same query as you did on the command-line