# Compiling C++/GTK within Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gcc, gtk

I'm fiddling around with the C/C++ version of Eclipse to build a simple GTK app. However, I can't seem to be able to compile a GTK sample from within Eclipse.

I think gtk is installed properly, used the ubuntu Package manager.

the code is:

```
#include <gtk-2.0/gtk/gtk.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    GtkWidget *window;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_widget_show  (window);

    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

and I have followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315091/compiling-c-gtk-within-eclipse/3459414#3459414) to set up the Command line patterns `"pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0"`

but I get these error:

```
Building file: ../src/GTKtestC.c
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/GTKtestC.d" -MT"src/GTKtestC.d" -o"src/GTKtestC.o" "../src/GTKtestC.c" pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0
gcc: pkg-config: No such file or directory
gcc: gtk+-2.0: No such file or directory
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-fcflags"
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-flibs"
make: *** [src/GTKtestC.o] Error 1
```

Getting a little frustrated, any help much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the backquotes.

Change the end of the command line to

```
`pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`
```

This means "take the output of the command between backquotes and replace this with its result".

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `libgtk2.0-dev`. Then change the `gtk+-2.0/gtk/gtk.h` to `gtk/gtk.h`, and (as klez said) change the end of the command line to:

```
`pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`
```